# Save one-hot-encoded features into Pandas DataFrame the fastest way

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a Pandas DataFrame with all my features and labels. One of my feature is categorical and needs to be one-hot-encoded.

The feature is an integer and can only have values from `0 to 4`

To save those arrays back in my DataFrame I use the following code

```
# enc is my OneHotEncoder object
df['mycol'] = df['mycol'].map(lambda x: enc.transform(x).toarray())
```

My DataFrame has more than 1 million rows so the above code takes a while.Is there a faster way to assign the arrays to the DataFrame cells? Because I have just 5 categories i dont need to call the `transform()` function 1 million times.

I already tried something like

```
num_categories = 5
i = 0
while (i<num_categories):
    df.loc[df['mycol'] == i, 'mycol'] = enc.transform(i).toarray()
    i += 1
```

Which yields this error

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
```

Comment: try `df['mycol'] = pd.factorize(df['mycol'])[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pd.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
>>> s
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
dtype: object

>>> pd.get_dummies(s)
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  1  0  0
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

>>> enc = OneHotEncoder()
>>> a = np.array([1, 1, 3, 2, 2]).reshape(-1, 1)
>>> a
array([[1],
       [1],
       [3],
       [2],
       [2]]

>>> one_hot = enc.fit_transform(a)
>>> one_hot.toarray()
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Comment: `get_dummies()` is, compared to my solution, pretty fast and also helps me to do the next step in my code (saving each element into a new column). thanks for your help!

Comment: also consider using OneHotEncoder because you can use it in a scikit-learn pipeline, so no need for an extra merge step.